# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: iframe, drupal-7

I am looking for some solution of this issue of iframe

```
domain.com/:1 Refused to display 'domain.com/?q=node/add/editor' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
domain.com/?q=node/add/editor 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
domain.com/:1 Refused to display 'domain.com/?q=node/add/editor' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
pay.webintellizer.com/?q=node/add/editor 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

FYI both sites are drupal based, if it has any special code.
I have already tested same domain and different domain both url for iframe but same error.

Comment: Most of the time this happens if you are trying to fetch the resource by using fetch method while you should only use link to point to this URL path

Answer (score 18):

As explained on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777934/195812 check your **x-frame-options** value

> ... they have disallowed loading of the resource in an iframe outside of their domain. So this iframe is not able to display cross domain.

[image]