# Image src isn't displaying after a time but link works in browser

Tags: html, image, iframe, instagram, src

I have an application where I show Instagram posts with their attributes (like/comment count, post thumbnail etc.). I use a private API with python to get those attributes.

I was using `<img>` tag and src attribute for showing post thumbnails, by giving this sample URL which is from API response:

https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/178658519_464414754779708_8788669411129849985_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=rB2avtcYIpAAX_iuOn2&edm=ABmJApABAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=efc659fa98302f5da1b68c0552e43278&oe=60B65A2D&_nc_sid=6136e7&ig_cache_key=MjU2MTE4MzMwMzE4NjgxODMxOA%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4

These post thumbnails were visible on my app as they should be, but after a time suddenly they are not visible anymore. I thought URL signatures are expired but that is not the reason, **when I click the link I gave above I can succesfully see thumbnail of the post.**

I also see in my console: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE"

To simplify:

My app is on django if it's relative. What is the thing that I'm missing out, it should be something simple I believe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572387/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-response)

Comment: Unfortunately no, if I use iframe instead of img I can see the image but cannot change the style. What I don't understand is, why I can show the image as an iframe but not as img?